# How to handle error 10486 in Paypal Digital Goods Express Checkout implementation

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

We intigrated **paypal digital goods express checkout api**. Few of my customers are getting **10486** error in GetExpressCheckoutPayment api call in live mode. After getting any error from paypal, we are stopping execution and showing a generic message. But we are getting Fatal error with our implementation. I am expecting that the target page is getting refreshing but I'm not sure about the functionality because I can't reproduce this issue in sandbox.

I need an **explantion on why paypal throws 10486 error** and also I want to know how to reproduce this error in sandbox mode.

Can any of you tell me **how to handle this 10486 error in digital goods api**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API Error Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/) a 10486 means

> Using the existing token, redirect the customer back to PayPal to
> select a different funding source or to add a new funding source. See
> this HowTo guide for more information.

In short, they want you to take your token from your original `SetExpressCheckout` call and redirect the user back to PayPal to start the process over again (don't make a new SEC call, just bounce them)